# Reponse to first request takes over 5 seconds in ASP.NET Core API app even with "Always On"

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API app running on Azure App Service with the Always On feature set.

The app is not getting a lot of hits because we're still in development stage. Having said that why would the initial request take over 5 seconds if the app is set to be always on?

It could be any request to any API endpoint of the app but I purposely choose a simple one and it still takes over 5 seconds for it to return a response.

After the first hit, everything is nice and fast. So, it's clearly an issue of the app going idle. I thought Always On would prevent the app from going idle.

Comment: Always On means it will not die, however after deploy it will not auto start, for auto start there is Application Startup Url which will be loaded as soon as app is deployed. And otherwise, what I would do is setup a post deploy trigger to fetch first request after deploy.

Comment: Akash Kava said is right, and the operation mechanism of the .net core program is such that it will not start immediately after deployment. I think you should ignore this phenomenon, because all .net web applications will have this problem. As for the idea of triggering after deployment, it can be added if your project needs it, but the problem of long initial access time still exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the comment of this [post](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1276). You will know what happened after the deployment and when the API was first called.

And in the official documentation, there is a word `Reduced “cold start” latency` is their remaining work. Therefore, the current `cold start` problem still exists. Setting `alway on` can prevents the program from sleeping like IIS.

And it is recommended to use [slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots)  switching when deploying again.When the time comes to switch the slot, it is also necessary to manually trigger the program to run, and then switch the deployment slot. At least this way, the user will not feel the phenomenon of service stalls.